# Double.toString without the exponential notation for large values

Tags: jsf, double, tostring, jsf-2.2

In my JSF2 application, I want my double value to be displayed without exponential notation. Is it possible?

I cannot use `NumberFormat` or `DecimalFormat` since its going to change my data type to String.

I understand from Java documentation, if my double value is less than 10^-3 or greater than or equal to 10^7, then it is represented in so-called "**computerized scientific notation**"(Ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString()).

And, In JSF while displaying a double value it will internally convert any data type to string.

For example, if my double value is `9999999999` it is getting displayed as `9.9e^9`. I want it to be displayed as it is. i.e `9999999999`

But, it there any possibility to override this character of Double or is there any other approach to solve this issue?

Comment: `toString` returns a String... `NumberFormat` and `DecimalFormat` do the same, they take a `Double` and create a `String`. Your `Double` value isn't changed.

Comment: True, but its internally JSF handles all conversion of data types. If I need to use NumberFormat or DecimalFormat, I need to handle or keep hold of two variables for a data

Comment: I do absolutely not understand why exactly you've a problem with the fact that JSF generates HTML output which is in essence one and all `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code provides a double or Double, you can display that value directly in the page using a converter:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.someDoubleValue}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="0"/>
</h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct solution for problems like this is to pass the internal data type around for as long as possible. Just at the moment when you display it to the user, you format it properly using `DecimalFormat`.

So you have to find all the places in your JSF2 UI where you display doubles and use the proper formatters there.

Note that `DecimalFormat` isn't threat safe, so you have to create a new formatter for each request (at least).

Comment: Thank you for your immediate reply. I want to know is there any possibility to do it without converting it to String? Because, its going to quite a lot of places where I need to use two variables for dealing one data.

Comment: Currently, you're relying on the default JSF formatters. All I'm saying is when you pass the data to the UI, inject your formatter. There will never be any need to have two variables because the formatted result will go to the web browser and you'll never see it again.