# How to format a number which is part of the value of p:outputLabel

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, el

I have this JSF .xhtml code:

```xml
<p:outputLabel value="#{bundle['my.bundle.name']} - #{Myclass.current.amount}"/>
```

`Myclass.current.amount` is a double in Java. There is a problem in conversion. For example, if `Myclass.current.amount` is equal to `10000000`, it's displayed like `1.0E7`, but I want `10000000`.

NOTE: I want a solution in JSF, not in Java.

I tried to use `<f:convertNumber/>` construction, but it didn't work, and this is not what I need in principle.

Comment: _"this is not what I need in principle"_ Why not?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Double.toString without the exponential notation for large values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039035/double-tostring-without-the-exponential-notation-for-large-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `f:convertNumber` only on components containing a number. If your component value is `Some text and #{bean.someNumber}`, it first evaluates the value, and the resulting string (for example `Some text and 1.0E7`) cannot be formatted using `f:convertNumber`.

It's not documented, but you can `p:outputLabel` without the `value` attribute, but use the body instead. So:

```html
<p:outputLabel for="...">Label value</p:outputLabel>
```

This allows you to place the number in its own component and format it:

```html
<p:outputLabel for="...">
  Some text
  <h:outputText value="#{testView.amount}">
    <f:convertNumber pattern="#"/>
  </h:outputText>
</p:outputLabel>
```